# Converting Geographic Coordinates to New York City neighboorhood names

Tags: data-request, geospatial, tool-request, api, geocoding

Does anyone know of a simple tool, method or dataset to enable someone to convert geographic coordinates to New York City neighborhood names?

At the very least, it would be good to map a dataset to the set of neighborhoods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking to figure this out, the trick is the following.

You'll need

1. Your file with long/lat coordinates in NYC. You can obtain these by geoencoding addresses
2. Use [this](http://nycdata.pediacities.com/dataset/pediacities-nyc-neighborhoods/resource/0f97a739-0a9f-442f-8105-43164d3af6f8) NYC neighborhoods geometry file
3. A [Cartodb](http://cartodb.com/) account.

Once you have all three, log into cartodb and upload your file with long/lat coordinates and the nyc neighborhood geometry file. Then follow these instructions:

1. Geoencode the long/lat coordinates as a goemetry object in your long/lat coordinate file.
2. Run the following SQL query from within the file:

   SELECT s.*,n.neighborhood   FROM {{yourFileName}} as s, nyc_pediacities_neighborhoods_v3_polygon as n   WHERE ST_Within(s.the_geom,n.the_geom)

You're creating two objects, yourFile as s and the shapefile as n, then matching the geometries against one another with the `WHERE` clause.

That should create a new column with rows featuring the NYC neighborhood of the long/lat of the same row.

3 . Export your file.

Comment: The polygon file for NYC neighborhoods would be much easier to use than Shapefiles, such as from Zillow.

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode Thanks but this is so easy. You just upload then run a query. What's the advantage?

Answer (score 6):

tamu has a killer geocoder, as well as a definitive list of other free geocoders. all you have to do is upload your data
http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/BatchProcess/
http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/OtherGeocoders/

Comment: Do you have any advice on using these services for this project? I am testing it now but not seeing how I'd do this. It seems like I would need to upload my own neighborhood data as well as my own latitude coordinates (my dataset). Then I could match them. Does that correspond to your process?

Comment: i would create a spreadsheet...anything .csv with name, lat, lon, and other corresponding headers. easiest would be google docs.

Comment: I just posted my solution. I am very curious to see yours as I am limited by the Maps API ratelimit (2500 queries per day) and my dataset is much larger.

Comment: they have a limit? huh. we work around that in my brigade by getting more than 1 person contribute...streety smarts offers free geocoding for non-profits....

Comment: I just tried this it does NOT work. Gives addresses but not neighborhood.

Answer (score 5):

Zillow provides Shapefiles for neighborhoods for the largest US Cities (includes NYC) for free (CC license). You can find them here:

http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm

Comment: Could you walk me through how to use a shapefile Pythonically or in R?

Comment: Hi I was unable to make these work. Could you help please?